# How to Invalidate all the requests for Expired API versions in URI Path with response like 410:Gone in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, api-versioning

If  I have a new version of API implemented using API versioning of the form
`/api/v3/example/resource`,   and I wish to Reject request of form `/api/v1/**`,  `/api/v2/**` etc.
for all the requests having this structure, how can i do that ??

Comment: You can use spring-security to only allow authorized individuals to access v1 and v2 of your API (Like the user with ROLE_ADMIN). and have v3 be open to access by anyone.

Comment: @AkashJain that's not what the OP wants -- that would give a 401 status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following request handling method to your controller with mappings for all your deprecated paths:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/v1/**", "/api/v2/**"})
public ResponseEntity<?> deprecatedVersions() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.GONE);
}
```

Comment: This could also be modeled with `501 (Not Implemented)` or `400 (Bad Request)`. It's a _bad request_ because the client doesn't know how to call the server properly.